# How to calculate the accuracy in Spacy module?

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have developed a Named Entity Recognition module and trying to calculate it's accuracy through Spacy.scorer

I have executed the below code and it has given me a error.

code

```
example = [
    ('Home page', 
    [(0,9,'USER INTERFACE')]),
    ('login form',
    [(10,20, 'MAIN COMPONENT')]),
    ('type should',
    [26,30, 'MINI COMPONENT'])
]

def evaluate(nlp1, doc):
    scorer = Scorer()
    for input_, annot in doc:
        doc_gold_text = nlp1.make_doc(input_)
        gold = GoldParse(doc_gold_text, entities=annot)
        pred_value = nlp1(input_)
        scorer.score(pred_value, gold)
    return scorer.scores
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How should i calculate the accuracy, recall and precision ?

Comment: You have a typo in your `example` definition

Comment: To do in spacy V3 follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68151189/12201407